# erro ao final do loop no slide show

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte JS

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var indexAtiva = 0;
  const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').item(0).getElementsByTagName('li');

  function slider() {

    for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

      if (i != indexAtiva) {
        lis[i].classList.remove('ativa');
      } else {
        lis[i].className = 'ativa'
      }
    }

    if ((indexAtiva + 1) == lis.length) {
      indexAtiva = 0;
    } else {
      indexAtiva++;
    }

    setTimeout(slider, 3000);

  }

  slider();
  
  var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
  var nav = slider.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
  var anterior = nav.getElementsByClassName('anterior')[0]
  var proximo = nav.getElementsByClassName('proximo')[0]
  
  anterior.onclick = function(){
   prev = indexAtiva - 1    
   prev = prev.length ? prev : lis[ lis.length - 1 ];  
   mostraBloco(prev);
  }
  
  proximo.onclick = function(){
   next = indexAtiva + 1    
      next = next.length ? next : lis[0];    
   mostraBloco(next);   
  }
// Função para exibir as imagens 
  function mostraBloco(next) {
   ativa = document.getElementsByClassName('ativa')
   ativa[0].classList.remove('ativa')  
   next.className = 'ativa'
  }

}
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
 outline:0;
}

body {
 width:100vw;
}


ul {
 list-style: none;
}
  .fade {
   -webkit-animation-name: fade;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
   animation-name: fade;
   animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
 opacity: .4
 }
  to {
 opacity: 1
 }
  }
  @keyframes fade {
  from {
 opacity: .4
 }
  to {
 opacity: 1
 }
  }  
@keyframes slider {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);        
    } 
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1);     
    }
}  

div.slider {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
div.slider ul.slide {
}
div.slider ul.slide li{
 display:none;
}

.ativa{
 display:block !important; 
}

div.slider ul.slide li img {
    position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 animation: slider 1s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
div.slider ul.slide li span {
    position:absolute;
 width: 100px;
 left: calc(50% - 50px);
 line-height:40px;
    bottom:0;
 text-align:center;
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 z-index:2; 
}

  div.slider nav {
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:40px;
      bottom:0;
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      z-index:1;
  }
  div.slider nav button {
      position:absolute;
      width:150px;
      height:100%;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  div.slider nav  button.anterior {
      left: 10%;
  }
  div.slider nav  button.proximo {
      right: 10%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slide">
     <li class="ativa">
        <img class="fade" src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
        <span>Este é 1</span>
     </li>
     <li>
        <img class="fade" src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
        <span>Este é 2</span>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <nav>
    <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
    <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Meu objetivo é pegar uma `UL` com suas `Lis` e mostrar uma a uma. 
Mas não todas de uma vez.

O erro é o seguinte: o slide roda normalmente. Mas quando chega no final, ele trava e o console não mostra o erro.

Onde estará o erro?

Obs.: se eu retiro a parte que está abaixo de

```
slider();
```

toda, então o slider roda normal. Ou seja, o problema deve estar nos botões de navegação

Segue o link online

http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index5.php

Comment: utilize o snippet para incluir o html + css + js em sua pergunta

Comment: feito leandro. inseri na pergunta

Comment: na verdade parece que nem está navegado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos problemas está em que você criou um objeto com o mesmo nome da função:

`function slider() {` e `var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]`

Isso irá gerar conflito porque o objeto `slider` deixa de ser uma função neste ponto:

```
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')
```

A solução é ou mudar o nome da função ou da variável, e não os dois com o mesmo nome. Por exemplo:

```
var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
var nav = slider1.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
```

Outra coisa redundante é o `for`, que não necessita desse `if` dentro dele.

Em relação aos botões, você pode aproveitar a função `slider()` dispensando funções extras, como fez. Basta você diferenciar o clique no botão <kbd>Anterior</kbd>, colocando um parâmetro `true`, para que a função saiba que ele foi clicado. No caso do botão <kbd>Próximo</kbd> não precisa, porque a função por padrão já passa os slides para frente.

Veja funcionando:

```js
window.onload = function() {
   var indexAtiva = 0;
   const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').item(0).getElementsByTagName('li');

   function slider(s) {

      for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
         lis[i].classList.remove('ativa');
      }

      // aqui irá tratar o clique no "Anterior".
      // É preciso tratar de 3 formas diferentes
      // dependendo do valor de indexAtiva.
      // Veja que o valor de indexAtiva, em cada caso,
      // irá receber o valor do índice ativado
      if(s){
         // significa que o próximo a mostrar será o
         // slide de índice 1, então está sendo exibido o 0.
         // neste caso eu ativo o último da array
         if(indexAtiva == 1){
            lis[lis.length-1].className = 'ativa';
            indexAtiva = lis.length-1;
            
         // aqui diz que está exibindo o último,
         // logo próximo será o primeiro (índice 0).
         // Então eu ativo o antepenúltimo da array
         }else if(indexAtiva == 0){
            lis[lis.length-2].className = 'ativa';
            indexAtiva = lis.length-2;
            
          // aqui é quando não for nenhum dos casos anteriores.
          // Eu diminuo 2 índices porque mais a frente será
          // incrementado com +1
         }else{
            lis[indexAtiva-2].className = 'ativa';
            indexAtiva -= 2;
         }
      }else{
         // aqui é quando for clicado o botão "próximo"
         // ou quando nenhum botão for clicado
         lis[indexAtiva].className = 'ativa';
      }

      indexAtiva = indexAtiva + 1 == lis.length ? 0 : indexAtiva+=1;

      tempo = setTimeout(slider, 3000);
   }

   slider();
   
   var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
   var nav = slider1.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
   var anterior = nav.getElementsByClassName('anterior')[0]
   var proximo = nav.getElementsByClassName('proximo')[0]
   
   anterior.onclick = function(){
      clearTimeout(tempo);
      slider(true);
   }
   
   proximo.onclick = function(){
      clearTimeout(tempo);
      slider();
   }

}
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
 outline:0;
}

body {
 width:100vw;
}


ul {
 list-style: none;
}
  .fade {
   -webkit-animation-name: fade;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
   animation-name: fade;
   animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
 opacity: .4
 }
  to {
 opacity: 1
 }
  }
  @keyframes fade {
  from {
 opacity: .4
 }
  to {
 opacity: 1
 }
  }  
@keyframes slider {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);        
    } 
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1);     
    }
}  

div.slider {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
div.slider ul.slide {
}
div.slider ul.slide li{
 display:none;
}

.ativa{
 display:block !important; 
}

div.slider ul.slide li img {
    position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 animation: slider 1s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  height: 180px;
}
div.slider ul.slide li span {
    position:absolute;
 width: 100px;
 left: calc(50% - 50px);
 line-height:40px;
    bottom:0;
 text-align:center;
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 z-index:2; 
}

  div.slider nav {
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:40px;
      bottom:0;
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      z-index:1;
  }
  div.slider nav button {
      position:absolute;
      width:150px;
      height:100%;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  div.slider nav  button.anterior {
      left: 10%;
  }
  div.slider nav  button.proximo {
      right: 10%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slide">
     <li class="ativa">
        <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
        <span>Este é 1</span>
     </li>
     <li>
        <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
        <span>Este é 2</span>
     </li>
     <li>
        <img class="fade" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" />
        <span>Este é 3</span>
     </li>
     <li>
        <img class="fade" src="https://www.salford.ac.uk/__data/assets/image/0008/890072/varieties/lightbox.jpg" />
        <span>Este é 4</span>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <nav>
    <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
    <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: entendi. só que surgiu outro problema. os botões proximo e anterior só rodam dentro de cada loop. Isto é, se estiver na ultima imagem de um loop ele não passa para a primeira do loop seguinte

Comment: ok, obrigado, na espera

Comment: na verdade parece que nem está navegando

Comment: é impressão minha ou o botão anterior ficou igual ao próximo?

Comment: Veja se resolve agora.

Comment: não só resolveu como foi perfeito para mim. Obrigado. Agora vou estudar esse teu código.

Comment: Blz... vou adicionar uns comments no código para ajudar a entender a parte do click no "anterior".

Answer (score 0):

Creio que encontrei o erro nos botões:

no bloco

```
prev = indexAtiva - 1      
prev = prev.length ? prev : lis[ lis.length - 1 ];  
mostraBloco(prev);
```

a lógica está levemente errada. Isso por que, digamos: o index máximo é 4. Está no momento na no quinto slide (index 4).

```
prev = 4 - 1 // =3
prev = prev.length ? prev : lis[ lis.length - 1 ];// false, o valor de prev é 3 aqui, nunca vai executar.
```

o mesmo erro ocorre no outro botão. A solução é simples: faça a condição sem aumentar/diminuir. Se verdadeiro, volte para o zero/avance para o 4. Se falso, adicione/retire 1. Desta forma:

```
prev = indexAtiva; 
prev == 0 ? lis[indexAtiva] = lis[lis.length] : lis[ lis[indexAtiva] - 1 ];
mostraBloco(prev);

next = indexAtiva
next == lis.length ? lis[indexAtiva] = lis[0] : lis[ lis[indexAtiva] + 1 ];
mostraBloco(next);
```

(fiz nova resposta pois não pude comentar a resposta do dvd)

Comment: Desculpe, voce disse que o index máximo é 4. Se isso se refere ao número de imagens, no momento só há 2 imagens e não 4. Mas isso não deve ser contado assim, afinal esse numero pode ser mudado dependendo da situaçao

Comment: o index 4 foi um exemplo, não sabia o limite, assumi que eram 5 imagens para exemplificar. Se o limite atual é 2, então substitua o valor de 4 por 2 no exemplo e dará no mesmo.
Sobre a parte de não dever ser contado assim pois a quantidade de slides podem mudar, nisso você está correto e com o conhecimento que tenho não consigo pensar aqui numa forma de direcionar exatamente pro começo ou fim da lista independente de quantas informações tenha, apenas tentei explicar o por que o ''if'' não estava funcionando corretamente

Comment: Oh Mateu, muito obrigado. Consegui entender. mas acho que do jeito que colocxou não estão fucnionando os botões. Vou procurar pelo erro. Você já ajudou bastante amigão!

Comment: Fiz um monte de erros no exemplo que dei, tenta agora.
(desculpa pela bagunça que fiz antes)


    prev = indexAtiva;
    prev = 0 ? lis[lis.length] : lis[ lis.length - 1 ];
    mostraBloco(prev);


    next = indexAtiva
    next = list.length ? lis[0] : lis[ lis.length + 1 ];    
    mostraBloco(next);


não estou conseguindo editar para ficar em forma de código não sei por que, vê se entende. ....

Comment: Aqui, dá uma olhada se fiz direito. Pois não quer trocar as imagens quando clica nos botões.http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index5.php

Comment: Tem algum problema ainda na página, os botões ainda não funcionam, mas é por outra razão. Se abrir o console vai ver "Uncaught TypeError: slider.getElementsByTagName is not a function
    at window.onload". 
Não entendo muito de referencia a objetos em js puro, sempre usei jQuery, então não vou poder te ajudar nessa, mas pelo que o erro apresenta erro na linha 3 do seu script. Vou dar uma checada e vejo se consigo achar o erro pra você.

Comment: Encontrei. Na variável ''nav'', você se referiu a variável ''slide'' como ''slider'' com o R no final, está causando erro na página. Tenta resolver isso e verifica se os botões funcionam.

Comment: Aliás, encontrei outro erro no script q eu mesmo escrevi. Sigh. em lis[ lis.length + 1 ], o correto seria lis[ IndexAtiva + 1], ou -1 no outro botão. Caso contrário ele não vai aumentar ou diminuir a posição da lista, vai adicionar ou remover itens da lista como se fosse um novo valor em uma array, e na condição ''true'' do if, teria que ser lis[indexAtiva] = lis[lis.length], ou no outro botão, = lis[0]
btw, no botão de ''proximo'' você escreveu ''list'' ao invés de lis, e ao comparar prev/next com algo use == ao invés de =.

Comment: Alterei mas continua sem trocar as imagens

Comment: Altera a sua solução para a mais completa?

Comment: Pronto, verifica agora

Comment: onde está? Alterou na pergunta? não funcionou! Vou atualizar online! http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index4.php